# Simple proof about linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

$V_F$ is a finite dimensional vector space.If the only subspaces of V are V and 0 then dim(V)=1

Comment: (supposing $V \neq \{0\}$ ) Pick a nonzero vector $v$. The span $span(v)$ is always a subspace. But since the only subspaces are 0 and V, you get $span(v)=V$. Thus, V is spanned by a single vector, so V has dimension 1

Comment: This question needs an additional assumption. If $V=\{0\}$ then $\dim V = 0$.

Comment: Do you have a question about this?

Comment: @RandyMarsh, nice!  Do we need an additional assuption, or can we not say that the zero-dimensional space $V$ containing only the zero vector satisfies the hypothesis.

Comment: @mjw We can (with an explanation why it violates the conclusion). But presumably the intent of the question is to prove the conclusion for non-zero finite dimensional spaces and OP just made a typo.

Comment: @RandyMarsh, The question should have asked that $V$ and $\{0\}$ are the only subspaces?  If so, why does it violate the conclusion?

Comment: @mjw The question should have assumed that $V$ is a non-zero finite dimensional space. Otherwise for $V=\{0\}$ both $V$ and $\{0\}$ are the only subspace, yet $\dim\{0\}=0$. That English grammar uses a plural doesn't matter, there's no assumption that the subspaces have to be distinct, grammar of a particular language doesn't take precedence over logic.

Comment: @RandyMarsh, right, I follow!   The OP wants to conclude that dim $V = 1.$   Agreed that logic bests grammar.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v\neq 0 \in V$and $<v>=span(v)$ is a subspace of $V$. We know the only subspaces are$\{ 0\} $ and $V$. Also we know $v\neq 0\Rightarrow <v> \neq <0>=\{0\}$ then must be $<v>=V$ that say's $dimV=1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  If $\rm{dim}V\gt1$, then take $\vec v\ne0$ and consider the span of $\vec v$.  This will be a one-dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 0):

$p$: dim $V=1$,

$q$: the only subspaces are {{0},$V$}

$\neg q \Rightarrow \neg p$

If there is another subspace, say $V'$, then there is an element, different from 0, in $V$ that is not in $V'$. Since the dim$V' \geq 1$, then that element increases the dimension of $V$ by 1, so dim$V \geq 2$

$\neg p \Rightarrow \neg q$

If dim$V \geq 2$, then, there are, at least, two elements in $V$ that are linearly independent, then there are at least two subspaces, other than {0}.

Comment: You need to prove that there is such a subspace $V'$. This is not the case for $V=\{0\}$.

Comment: the assumption are that the only subspaces are {0} and $V$, right ?

Comment: Yes. There is no assumption that the two are distinct.

Comment: What you are saying is completely right, but your answer is proving $\sim p \implies \sim q $ which is not always equivalent to $p\implies q$.

Comment: it needs the implication in the other direction